# Why does the date format YW fail at the start of 2023?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I store data in the form of year and week in my code (for example 202305 or 202310) in order to do this, I use the Date function in PHP as follows:

```
$weekNum = (int) date('YW', $myDate);
```

Where $myDate is a timestamp. This approach works well as it provides a nice sequential number to sort my data on.

However I noticed that at the start of this year (2023) the week number came up as 52 and $weekNum was set to 202352. This disrupted my system because now I have 202352 followed by 202301 and sequencing shows a week that is into the future.

Any help or explanation on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Looking up `W` in the PHP manual would have told you, this represents the _"ISO 8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday"_ And if you are not aware what "ISO 8601 week number" means, you could have easily googled that - first result it brings me, already explains: _"The ISO 8601 rule is: The first week of the year is the week containing the first Thursday. So if January 1 falls on a Friday, it belongs to the last week of the previous year. If December 31 falls on a Wednesday, it belongs to week 01 of the following year."_

Comment: Do not use Y with W. There is a specific year definition to be used with ISO weeks (it happens for non-complete weeks at beginning (or end) of year

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: What makes you think that the date format "failed"? How does it "disrupt" your system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments correctly identify the source of the problem and CBroe gives a nice description for how the dates can change at the start of the year. However, this problem, in my opinion, is not as obvious as implied by the comments and these don't suggest a solution.

Fortunately the solution is straightforward, you need to change your code to:

```
$weekNum = (int) date('oW', $myDate);
```

The 'o' is ISO-8601 year number and has the same value as Y, except when the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year when that year is used instead and your first entry of the year would have been 202252.

This is a subtle though easy mistake to make and I think that this is a good question, as it will undoubtedly show other programmers how to handle ISO week formats.

Comment: Thank you, nice clear answer, I will make the change.